# Php code to detect mobilie or tab

Tags: php

I have downloaded a php code to detect device(means mobile or tablet). It is working coreect but. But after detecting when i am trying to redirect into another page it is not working

[Here is the detect method i have call](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8tGQEzyfKnbd1JTbk5KY00zbG8/edit?usp=sharing)

and the code is below

```
$detec=detectBrowser();
if($detec==true)
{   

header("location: http://www.google.com"); 
}
```

It is printing hello but not redirecting.

Comment: Take a look at the error that you are suppressing with `@`. If you remove the `@` you'll see why it's not working.

Comment: @rid - it's obviously not that obvious if the error messages are being suppressed :)

Comment: i have also checked it without @

Comment: removed echo but not working

Comment: You can't have output before headers. If you weren't suppressing errors you'd... see the error.

Comment: Are you now seeing any error messages? Make sure that you have error reporting turned on...

Comment: no there is no error. I have turned on the error reporting

Comment: I think PHP is supposed to be exited immediately after a header:Location call. Have you tried adding a die or exit directly after your header call? 

Otherwise php will try to continue to execute the code underneath the header call ... have a go with an 'exit' added in and see if you get any different results!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second line of your PHP file (after `<?php`):

```
// Turn on ALL error reporting
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Detection code:

```
$detect = detectBrowser();
if($detect == true) {
   // The user is using a mobile device. Proceed to the next URL.
   header("Location: http://www.url.com/mobile/");
} else {
   // The user is not using a mobile device.
   header("Location: http://www.url.com/non-mobile/");
}
```

Try this code. It checks if the user is NOT on a mobile device, it redirects to a non-mobile device, or if the user is using a mobile device, then it goes to the mobile site.